# Pyspark Unable To subscribe to Kafka Topic

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

Kafka (2.8.0) is runing on port 9092 and zookeeper (3.5.9) is running on port 2181.
Kafka producer is also running for topic named “kafka-spark” and kafka console is successfully receiving the messages.

Now, I want to connect pyspark and kafka for which my kafkaspark.py file is as follows:

```
import findspark
findspark.init("/usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7")
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

KAFKA_TOPIC = "kafka-spark"
KAFKA_SERVER = "localhost:9092"

# creating an instance of SparkSession
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark create RDD").getOrCreate()

# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = spark_session \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .load()
print(df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)"))
print(df)
```

My spark submit command is:

`spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12:3.1.2 /usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python/kafkaspark.py localhost 9092 kafka-spark`

Now the output of this command is (No error):

```
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/abc/.ivy2/jars
org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency
org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-be2fbd70-4508-4a0e-9a46-397b1e82e2ca;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.1.2 in central
    found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.1.2 in central
    found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.6.0 in central
    found com.github.luben#zstd-jni;1.4.8-1 in central
    found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.7.1 in central
    found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.2 in central
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.30 in central
    found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.6.2 in central
    found org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12;3.1.2 in central …
…............................
21/09/02 14:53:05 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse'.
DataFrame[key: string, value: string]
DataFrame[key: binary, value: binary, topic: string, partition: int, offset: bigint, timestamp: timestamp, timestampType: int]
21/09/02 14:53:06 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.57.138.181:4040
21/09/02 14:53:06 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
21/09/02 14:53:06 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
21/09/02 14:53:06 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
21/09/02 14:53:06 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
21/09/02 14:53:06 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
21/09/02 14:53:07 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
21/09/02 14:53:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/09/02 14:53:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-c4b197d7-99dc-4c57-a188-dc83a759efb8
21/09/02 14:53:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-9192d7d1-5f14-4394-bf0c-9cdf4d9b31b6
21/09/02 14:53:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-9192d7d1-5f14-4394-bf0c-9cdf4d9b31b6/pyspark-57958f93-13f2-4dd0-a797-ca9650906dab
```

According to my understanding the message in the topic should stream on the spark console but the pyspark server keeps shutting down without subscribing to the topic. Please help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by invoking 'print(df)'? df is just a representation of the data, not the data itself. You need to collect it (not advised) into the Driver in order to use/print it.

Comment: You want `df.writeStream.format("console")`